# Can't post image to Twitter. Received authentication challenge is null

Tags: android, twitter4j

After the login flow, I store access token and accesss token secret in prefs. Now I want to post image to Twitter using TwitPic.

**Updated:** I tried to set date&time on device to automatic. The callback URL in my Twitter app exists. It still shows error.

My code

```
public static boolean tweetMessageAndPhoto(final String message, final String photoPath) {
    final ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken(getAccessTokenStr());
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(getAccessTokenSecretStr());
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constant.CONSUMER_KEY);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
    cb.setMediaProviderAPIKey(Constant.MEDIA_KEY);              
    final Configuration conf = cb.build();

    final ImageUpload upload = new ImageUploadFactory(conf).getInstance(MediaProvider.TWITPIC);

    try {
        final String uri = upload.upload(new File(photoPath), message);
        System.out.println("================URI: " + uri);
        return true;
    } catch (final TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ShowLog.showLogError(TAG, "Could not tweet. Please try again.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

I get this error:

```
W/System.err(14566): Received authentication challenge is nullRelevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
W/System.err(14566):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ea09dc6d or
W/System.err(14566):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=049b821e
W/System.err(14566): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[ea09dc6d-049b821e 0237e8c8-8ed4bd69], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.3}
W/System.err(14566):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:204)
W/System.err(14566):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
W/System.err(14566):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:114)
W/System.err(14566):    at twitter4j.media.AbstractImageUploadImpl.upload(AbstractImageUploadImpl.java:111)
W/System.err(14566):    at twitter4j.media.AbstractImageUploadImpl.upload(AbstractImageUploadImpl.java:80)
W/System.err(14566):    at app.jp.cropnet.twitter.TwitterHelper.tweetMessageAndPhoto(TwitterHelper.java:121)
W/System.err(14566):    at app.jp.cropnet.twitter.TwitterDemoActivity.tweetMessageAndPhoto(TwitterDemoActivity.java:81)
W/System.err(14566):    at app.jp.cropnet.twitter.TwitterDemoActivity.access$1(TwitterDemoActivity.java:78)
W/System.err(14566):    at app.jp.cropnet.twitter.TwitterDemoActivity$2.onClick(TwitterDemoActivity.java:40)
W/System.err(14566):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)
W/System.err(14566):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8890)
W/System.err(14566):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
W/System.err(14566):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err(14566):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err(14566):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
W/System.err(14566):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(14566):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
W/System.err(14566):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
W/System.err(14566):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
W/System.err(14566):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err(14566): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
W/System.err(14566):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1694)
W/System.err(14566):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1649)
W/System.err(14566):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1374)
W/System.err(14566):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:117)
W/System.err(14566):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:35)
W/System.err(14566):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:168)
W/System.err(14566):    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using simulator, this should work fine, 
and if you are getting error only on real device, please check that the sim card you inserted in the phone has automatic time update feature enable.
I once got into the problem, changing sim card from other network solved my problem.

Comment: Where can I check it? I go through Settings but don't see SIM card datetime. One more question: What if it is a tablet without SIM card?

Comment: I tested it on Samsung GT-I9000 and KindleFire. They have the same problem.

Comment: I think device time should be updated by wifi, and you should set your time zone correctly.

Comment: My timezone is GMT+7. I set it and check "auto datetime" in Datetime setting. @_@